# Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/netty/transport/ClientTransport

Tags: java, azure-keyvault, reactor-netty, azure-sdk, azure-identity

I am developing a jar file to upload in an application which will utilise it to connect to Azure key vault and retrieve credential to further run some actions on servers. I am using Maven and is stuck on this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/netty/transport/ClientTransport
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

This is the code section:

```
ClientCertificateCredential clientCertificateCredential = new ClientCertificateCredentialBuilder()
    .tenantId(TenantID)
    .clientId(ClientID)
    .pfxCertificate(CertificatePath, CertificatePassword)
    .build();
            
    SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
    .vaultUrl(keyVaultUrl)
    .credential(clientCertificateCredential)
    .buildClient();
```

I have tried quite a few versions of dependencies but still not able to resolve it as i am new to this. Stuck on it for a few days now. This is how the dependency section looks like:

```
<!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.26.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have already tried a few versions of the dependencies but i am new to this and not able to figure out.

Update:
I added the azure bom in pom file, still getting the error slightly changed though:

```
       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/netty/transport/ClientTransport at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder.build(NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder.java:141) at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientProvider.createInstance(NettyAsyncHttpClientProvider.java:19) at com.azure.core.implementation.http.HttpClientProviders.createInstance(HttpClientProviders.java:67) at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.createDefault(HttpClient.java:50) at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.createDefault(HttpClient.java:40) at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineBuilder.build(HttpPipelineBuilder.java:73) at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(SecretClientBuilder.java:225) at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder.buildClient(SecretClientBuilder.java:147) at com.snc.discovery.CredentialResolver.resolve(CredentialResolver.java:177) at com.service_now.mid.services.CredentialResolverProxy.resolveWithSemaphore(CredentialResolverProxy.java:392) at com.service_now.mid.services.CredentialResolverProxy.lambda$resolveFromVault$1(CredentialResolverProxy.java:329) at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) at com.service_now.mid.services.CredentialResolverProxy.resolveFromVault(CredentialResolverProxy.java:329) at com.service_now.mid.services.CredentialResolverProxy.lambda$resolve$0(CredentialResolverProxy.java:313) at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) at com.service_now.mid.services.CredentialResolverProxy.resolve(CredentialResolverProxy.java:313) at com.service_now.mid.creds.provider.standard.HighSecurityCredential.callResolver(HighSecurityCredential.java:55) at com.service_now.mid.creds.provider.standard.HighSecurityCredential.getAttribute(HighSecurityCredential.java:177) at com.snc.automation_common.integration.creds.Credential.isMidServerServiceAccount(Credential.java:151) at com.service_now.mid.win.powershell.api.APowershellSession.testCredential(APowershellSession.java:416) at com.service_now.mid.win.powershell.api.PowerShellConnectionFactory.getConnection(PowerShellConnectionFactory.java:60) at com.service_now.mid.win.powershell.api.PowerShellConnectionFactory.getConnection(PowerShellConnectionFactory.java:22) at com.snc.core_automation_common.util.AKeyedConnectionFactory.getConnectionUseOneCred(AKeyedConnectionFactory.java:266) at com.snc.core_automation_common.util.AKeyedConnectionFactory.getConnectionIterateOverCreds(AKeyedConnectionFactory.java:208) at com.snc.core_automation_common.util.AKeyedConnectionFactory.getConnection(AKeyedConnectionFactory.java:158) at com.snc.core_automation_common.util.AKeyedConnectionFactory.getConnection(AKeyedConnectionFactory.java:145) at com.snc.core_automation_common.util.AKeyedConnectionFactory.getConnection(AKeyedConnectionFactory.java:133) at com.service_now.mid.pipeline.command.TestCredentialCommandImpl.executeRawCommand(TestCredentialCommandImpl.java:126) at com.snc.core_automation_common.pipeline.ACommand.execute(ACommand.java:114) at com.service_now.mid.probe.CommandPipeline.probe(CommandPipeline.java:67) at com.service_now.mid.probe.AProbe.process(AProbe.java:155) at com.service_now.mid.queue_worker.AWorker.runWorker(AWorker.java:131) at com.service_now.mid.queue_worker.AWorkerThread.run(AWorkerThread.java:20) at com.service_now.mid.threadpool.ResourceUserQueue$RunnableProxy.run(ResourceUserQueue.java:640) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: This is a Java problem yet you have not tagged your question "java" even though you say you are creating a JAR. If you have a stack trace (for the `NoClassDefFoundError`) then [edit] your question and post the entire stack trace. At a guess, I would say there are classes missing in the JAR file you created. `NoClassDefFoundError` generally indicates that a class that was in the CLASSPATH when you compiled your Java code is not in the CLASSPATH when you run that compiled code. So either the JAR is missing files or a referenced library is missing.

Comment: @Beena Dagar Try using `clientsecretcredential` refer to this  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/identity-service-principal-auth#client-secret-credential

Comment: @Abra I have added the trace. I have to use the jar file in Servicenow application, so external jars have to be uploaded as well. I have added all that i can think of, cant figure out which one is missing.

Comment: @Venkatesan i have to use certificate authentication, secret is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to resolve the error by excluding `azure-core-http-netty` from the azure dependencies (azure-identity and azure-security-keyvault-secrets) and adding `azure-core-http-okhttp` artifact.
Referenced this thread:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/19041